# Ocilib for Suse 10.3

Tags: linux, unix, oracle-call-interface, suse

Where could I find ocilib for Suse 10.3?
I need to communicate with oracle from this os. Our admin won't make any upgrade and I can't use the newest version because he gets a lot of dependency problems while installing it.
Is ocilib the best way to communicate with oracle from c? Or is there any alternative? I need anything, what is supported and available for Suse 10.3.

Answer (score 0):

Just download OCILIB and compile it on any OpenSuse 10.3 machine. 
And then deploy the shared lib wihtin your application ! You'll just have to care your paths and environment variables.
If you can compile and install it on the target machine it its even easier !